# R/exams: how to select different font type for pdfs

Tags: r, latex, r-exams

HI am pretty new to coding with R/LaTeX and currently trying to figure out how to set up exams using R/exams. While I have already managed to create the exercises themselves, I now want to save them as pdfs using exams2pdf.
However, I would like to use a different font than the one used by default. Does anyone know whether this is possible and, if so, how I have to add this to my code?

Is it also possible to change the "Header", where it says "1. Problem" to something else/remove it?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just another friendly reminder that resolving the question - either by acceptance of the answer or a more detailed follow-up - would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

#### Overview

In `exams2pdf()` there is the `template =` argument with which you can specify a master LaTeX template into which the individual exercises are embedded. By providing your own template you can change any aspect you like: fonts, page formatting, intro text, whether or not questions/solutions are shown, etc.

Below I give a rather detailed overview so that this post is also useful for other R/exams users that want to modify other aspects of the template in `exams2pdf()`.

#### Getting started

To get started I would recommend to go to a suitable working directory and then set up `exams_skeleton()` there, e.g.,

```
exams_skeleton(dir = ".", writer = "exams2pdf", markup = "markdown")
```

which copies all of the `.Rmd` exercises (due to the `markup = "markdown"` specification) available in R/exams to an `exercises/` folder, along with all available LaTeX templates to the `templates/` folder, and sets up two demo `.R` scripts: `demo-all.R` and `demo-pdf.R`. You can look at these, especially the latter, and play around with the examples provided there.

#### Vignette

More details and background information are then provided in a package vignette: `vignette("exams", package = "exams")`, especially Section 3.

#### The master LaTeX template

For doing the concrete adaptations you ask for, I would start by modifying the `plain.tex` template in the `templates/` directory. The "factory-fresh" default content is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{a4wide,color,Sweave,url,amsmath,booktabs,longtable,eurosym,amssymb}
\newenvironment{question}{\item \textbf{Problem}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\textbf{Solution}\newline}{}
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{(\alph{enumii})}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
\providecommand{\tightlist}{\setlength{\itemsep}{0pt}\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}}

\setkeys{Gin}{keepaspectratio}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
%% \exinput{exercises}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

***Changing question and solution formatting***

For example, you could decide to only show the question but not the solution by modifying the `{question}` and `{solution}` environments above to:

```
\usepackage{verbatim}
\newenvironment{question}{\item}{}
\newenvironment{solution}{\comment}{\endcomment}
```

***Changing the answer list formatting***

Then you could modify the answerlist from (a), (b), ... to A., B., by modifying the `{answerlist}` environment:

```
\newenvironment{answerlist}{\renewcommand{\labelenumii}{\Alph{enumii}.}\begin{enumerate}}{\end{enumerate}}
```

***Changing the font***

And finally you could modify the default font to Lato, say, by loading the `{lato}` package and using a dark gray (rather than the default black) font color. To do so insert before the `\begin{document}` line:

```
\usepackage[default]{lato}
\definecolor{darkgray}{rgb}{0.23,0.23,0.23}
\color{darkgray}
```

***Run exams2pdf() with new template***

And then to see the result, run:

```
exams2pdf("swisscapital.Rmd", edir = "exercises/", template = "templates/plain.tex")
```